# Invalid postback or callback argument after adding items to DropDownList using javascript and running server-side code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

Our `asp.net` webform has two `DropDownLists` (`DdlStatus` and `DdlPlanStatus`) and a "Search" button with server-side code.

Initially, the page would work this way: If `ListItem` "Plan" was selected in `DdlStatus` (that's always visible), then `DdlPlanStatus` would be displayed (using `javascript`) and the user would select from this 2nd `DropDownList` and do a search. If `ListItem` "Complete" was selected in `DdlStatus`, `DdlPlanStatus` would be hidden and a search was made. This works fine.

The new change was that the 2nd dropdown (`DdlPlanStatus`) would be visible with two `ListItems`. So essentially, If `ListItem` "Complete" was selected in `DdlStatus` `DdlPlanStatus` would have two `ListItems` to select from.

So this is essentially my `javascript` code:

```
function HideDropDown() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=DdlStatus.ClientID%>");
    var SelectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    var ddlParms = document.getElementById("<%=DdlPlanStatus.ClientID%>");
    if ((SelectedValue) == "Complete") {
        // ddlParms.style.display = "none";  //This was before, where I hid dropdown
        document.getElementById("<%=DdlPlanStatus.ClientID%>").options.length = 0;

        var opt = document.createElement("option");

        opt.text = "Complete";
        opt.value = "Complete";
        document.getElementById("<%=DdlPlanStatus.ClientID%>").options.add(opt);


        var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
        opt2.text = "Missing";
        opt2.value = "Missing";
        document.getElementById("<%=DdlPlanStatus.ClientID%>").options.add(opt2);

    }
    else {
        ddlParms.style.display = "block"; //display dropdown
    }
}
```

When "Complete" is selected in 1st dropdown, I clear the contents of the 2nd dropdown and add 2 items, instead of just hiding it.

The issue is that when I run the search, I get error. I'm almost sure it's because I'm adding the items using javascript:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using
<pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or 
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
```

Do I need to add those `ListItems` another way?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a very strange way of clearing the option list. Have you considered [other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box)?

Comment: Can you show us the aspx code and c# code for the search button?

Comment: @Andrei, I cleared the list using this other option, but I continue getting the error. So the issue is not the way I clear the dropdownlist.

Comment: @psoshmo: to be more specific, I get the error when I click the search button after I select "Complete" in the 1st dropdown and the server-side code reads the value from the 2nd dropdown.

Comment: Right, that's why I want to see the relevant code for the search button

Comment: When you enable eventvalidation, your dropdowns will register their events for all the values they have when being rendered, i.e. when your page get's created on server side. On postback/callback, the passed arguments (values of your dropdowns) get validated against the registered events. So, when you change the dropdowns values on client side (javascript) you have to either turn off eventValidation or change your dropdown list elements on server side.

Comment: @Markai, I think you're right. The items in the dropdownlist that are initially displayed when the page is rendered are added at design time.

Comment: You can read more about this behaviour here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Markai, very cool piece of info, thanks for sharing. Had no idea list controls register their items for validation purposes

Comment: I disabled eventvalidation, but the issue I'm having is that it doesn't recognize the new values in the dropdownlist. It just recognizes the old values.

Comment: For example, the first value of `DdlPlanStatus` (2nd dropdown) by default is "Plan". I change the first dropdownlist and now the 2nd dropdownlist has different values. When I click on search, the codebehind registers the value as "Plan" instead of "Complete" (the new value).

Comment: @Markai, if  you want to, you can post your answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

the error is caused by you alter the items of DdlPlanStatus at client side. If DdlPlanStatus always having two options ("Complete" and "Missing"), then you can do it in your aspx file instead of adding them at client side. For more info about EventValidation, please refer to

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/07/31/why-i-get-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-errors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you enable eventvalidation, your dropdowns will register their events for all the values they have when being rendered, i.e. when your page get's created on server side. On postback/callback, the passed arguments (values of your dropdowns) get validated against the registered events. So, when you change the dropdowns values on client side (javascript), the registered values don't match the actual values passed on postback/callback and an exception is being thrown. To avoid this, you have to either turn off eventValidation or use the `RegisterForEventValidation` function (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942244/how-should-registerforeventvalidation-be-used-correctly)). Or you change your dropdown list elements on server side if possible.

You can read more about the event validation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT: If the dropdown values are sensitive data and can cause security issues, it is not recommendable to turn off event validation. Instead it would be better to register all values that are acceptable.