# Calling asp.net webform postback from select2:select event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, jquery-select2

I am trying to trigger a postback handler when the user selects an option from a select2 dropdown. When I try using the code shown below, I receive the error message:

"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

I am looking for advice on a method to use the select2 event to trigger the postback and thus trigger loading new data based on the user selection

**ASCX control**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="uc_selector" EnableViewState="true" Codebehind="selector.ascx.vb" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Visible="False" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="txtID" runat="server"  />
<asp:ListBox ID="nameSelect" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#<%=nameSelect.ClientID%>").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            width: 'resolve',
            ajax: {
                url: "<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/")%>MyEndpoint.ashx",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data,
                            function(x) {
                                return {
                                    id: x.Id,
                                    text: x.Name
                                };
                            })
                    };
                }
            }
        });

        $("#<%=nameSelect.ClientID%>").on('select2:select', function (e) {
            $("#<%=txtID.ClientID%>").val(e.params.data.id);
            $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val(e.params.data.text);
            __doPostBack('<%=nameSelect.UniqueID%>', '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Protected Sub name_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nameSelect.TextChanged
    RaiseEvent TextChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to ajax to server from a server control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5953372/12971

Comment: @Win - yes with Ajav